# $G$ compact group and $T(x)=ax$. If $T$ is ergodic, then $\{a^n\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ is dense in $G$.

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

> **Theorem**. Let $G$ compact group and $T(x)=ax$. Then $T$ is ergodic iff $\{a^n\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ is dense in $G$. In particular, if $T$ is ergodic, then $G$ is abelian.

This is one direction of Theorem 1.9 in Peter Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory* and as far as I can tell it contains a mistake. The direction that I don't understand goes:

Suppose $T$ is ergodic. Let $H$ be the closure of the orbit of $a$. If $H \neq G$ then there exists a character $\hat{\gamma} \in \hat{G}$ with $\gamma=1$ on $H$ but $\gamma$ is not constant $1$. Then $\gamma(Tx) = \gamma(ax) = \gamma(a)\gamma(x) = \gamma(x)$ so $\gamma$ is not a.s. constant, contradicting ergodicity of $T$.

My problem with this is that Walters only defines $\hat{G}$ for abelian $G$. So what has he left out that is needed for this proof to go through? He clearly isn't assuming $G$ is abelian because that is one of the conclusions.

Comment: The theorem is true, but the proof is nonsense: There are compact groups without nontrivial characters. Do you already know that if an action is ergodic then a.e. orbit is dense. If you know thus result, then you are almost done.

Comment: @MoisheCohen the author remarks that this fact can be used instead if $G$ is metrizable, making it sound like this theorem is meant to apply even when $G$ isn't metrizable.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Just so I'm clear, supposing $G$ is metrizable and we get that a.e. orbit is dense. Then we may choose some $x$ such that $\{a^n x\}_n$ is dense, and hence $\{a^n\}_n$ is dense too since $A(y):=yx$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: very good, this is a correct proof. The  other argument is simply false, as I said there are groups without nontrivial characters, for instance any simple group.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I think Walters's proof is correct, and other authors (e.g. the book Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory) also have the result mentioned in the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: @Ryker: I am not questioning the result, but the proof that6 you wrote is plain false. What makes you think it is correct? Do you think that noncyclic simple compact groups do not exist?